# Guitar Notation E-Gt

Tags: notation

What does E-Gt at the beginning of a guitar piece mean? It's just left of the Clef.

I saw something online suggesting that it had something to do with overdrive vs clean guitar, but I couldn't confirm that anywhere.

Comment: Electric Guitar.

Comment: Exactly as @Bob said. To the left of a staff is where the staff's instrument is specified, and the instrument names are usually abbreviated.

Comment: @Patrx2, why not add your comment as an answer...?

Comment: Fair enough, @Bob. I was wondering why you hadn't. :D

Comment: Also sometimes abbreviated El-G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in Bob Bradley's comment, it means Electric Guitar. To the left of a staff is where the staff's instrument is specified, and the instrument names are usually abbreviated.